# Detecting ARKit compatible device from user agent

Tags: ios, user-agent, arkit

We would like to enable a feature that allows a model to be viewed using a deep link to our ARKit app from a web page.

Has anyone discovered a way to discover if a device is ARKit compatible using the user agent string or any other browser-based mechanism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari doesn’t expose any of the required hardware information for that.

If you already have a companion iOS app for your website, another option might be to still provide some non-AR experience for your content, so that the website has something to link to in all cases.

For example, AR furniture catalogs seem to be a thing now. But if the device isn’t ARKit capable, you could still provide a 3D model of each furniture piece linked from your website, letting the user spin it around and zoom in on it with touch gestures instead of placing it in AR.

Comment: Thanks rickster.  I'll do a test.  The case I wanted to avoid was a deep link taking the user to the AppStore to download the app, only to be told their device does not support ARKit.  I'll map out some possible workflows and see if there is a way to make the experience as painless as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Apple seems to use the following code to show/hide the "Visit this page on iOS 12 to try AR Quick Look" on https://developer.apple.com/arkit/gallery/

```
(function () {
    var isRelAR = false;
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    if (a.relList.supports('ar')) {
        isRelAR = true;
    }
    document.documentElement.classList.add(isRelAR ? 'relar' : 'no-relar');
})();
```

The interesting part of course being

```
    var isRelAR = false;
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    if (a.relList.supports('ar')) {
        isRelAR = true;
    }
```

Make your actions accordingly based on the value of isRelAR.